# Alternate of Except in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to get results from the following table. Get all ID and treetypes except Apple having Id=102.

```
Id         TreeType 
---------------------
99         Apple
99         Mango   
102        Orange  
101        Blackberry   
102        Apple
```

Result will be.

```
Id         TreeType 
---------------------
99         Apple
99         Mango   
102        Orange  
101        Blackberry
```

One way we can get result from following query.

```
select id, TreeType
from x

except

select id, TreeType
from x
where id = 102 and TreeType = 'Apple'
```

It it possible to get the result from one select statement?

I just want to avoid because of on actual scenario it become very costly for me.

Comment: `where id <> 102 OR treetype <> 'Apple'`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about just

```
SELECT id,TreeType
FROM x
WHERE NOT(id = 102 AND TreeType = 'Apple')
```

This did trip me up at first though - I wanted to think `WHERE (id <> 102 AND TreeType <> 'Apple')` would work but it doesn't.  This makes sense when you rethink it as a table of bools - in that case it'd be

```
id    opr.    TreeType
======================
true  AND     false    -- 99 apple: false
true  AND     true     -- 99 mango: true
true  AND     false    -- 102 orange: false
true  AND     true     -- 101 blackberry: true
false AND     true     -- 102 apple: false
```

Using the above syntax, we get just the row we want to target to be true and use `NOT`.

```
id    opr.    TreeType
======================
false AND     false     -- 99 apple: not(false) = true
false AND     false     -- 99 mango: not(false) = true
true  AND     false     -- 102 orange: not(false) = true
false AND     true      -- 101 blackberry: not(false) = true
true  AND     true      -- 102 apple: not(true) = false
```

Comment: No problem  - if this resolved your issue consider accepting the answer by hitting the green checkbox under the vote rocker.

Comment: Of course `NOT(id = 102 AND TreeType = 'Apple')` is not the same as `(id <> 102 AND TreeType <> 'Apple')` because the equivalent to your expression is `id <> 102 OR treetype <> 'Apple'` - this is [boolean algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan's_laws).

Answer (score 4):

Another solution is using `NOT EXISTS` like this-

```
SELECT id,TreeType
FROM x t
WHERE NOT EXISTS 
(
    SELECT 1 FROM x 
    WHERE 
        id = t.id AND TreeType = t.TreeType 
        AND id = 102 
        AND TreeType = 'Apple'
)
```